# List of domains on DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Is there a way to get a complete list of A and CNAME records on my BIND DNS server?

I have access to the zone files. But on my server there are lots of zone files, and it'd take too long to go over all of them by hand. Is there a command that lists this info or will I have to write a script myself?

Comment: O noes!  Not a script!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than use `grep` on all of the zone files, use:

```
% rndc dumpdb -zones
```

This will create a dump of the server's authoritative data called `named_dump.db`, probably in `/var/named/data` (or similar).

This file is easier to parse than the original zone files because every line starts with the domain name to which it applies.  The raw zone files are probably abbreviated.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed! Though the file was named named_dump.db in my case. Thanks :)

Comment: On Ubuntu it seems to end up in `/var/cache/bind/named_dump.db`

Answer (score 1):

From your `var/named/data` (or equivalent directory) grep through the db.* files with an appropriate regular expression, something like:

```
grep '\(.  *A   *[0-9][0-9]*\)\|\(..*CNAME..*\)' db.*
```

Note that the final 'db.*` globs all the db files.  Repeat for every directory you have zone files in.

Comment: That's what the find command is for! find /var/named/data -name 'db.*' -print0 | xargs -0 grep '...'

Answer (score -2):

for i in my domain list; do dig -t axfr $i @localhost; done

Have to allow zone transfers from localhost first.